# how to use ajax on anchor link

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I am working on a django application to display graphs. I want to use ajax with this application to prevent page refreshes. The problem is I don't know how to go about doing that with anchor tags. I tried ajax before with form submits. This is the code for form submit

```
$(document).on('submit', '.csv_upload_form', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    csvUploadAjax();
});

function csvUploadAjax() {
    let $form = $(".csv_upload_form");
    let form_data = new FormData($form[0]);
    $.ajax({
        url: $form.attr('action'),
        type: $form.attr('method'),
        data: form_data,
        dataType: 'html',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (data) {
            displayTable(data);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, err) {
            console.log("Something went wrong: " + err);
        }
    });
}
```

But I don't know how to replicate this on anchor tags. This is my code so far

**html template**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="{% url 'visualize' %}" class='link1'>Line Chart</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Scatterplot</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Bar Graph</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Pie Chart</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Heat Maps</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Histogram</a></li>
</ul>
```

**index.js**

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    onLinkClick();
})

function onLinkClick() {
    let $link = $('.link1');
    let link_data = new FormData($link[0]);
    $.ajax({
        url: $link.attr('action'),
        type: $link.attr('method'),
        data: link_data,
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (data) {
            showGraph(data);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, err) {
            console.log("Something went wrong: " + err);
        }
    });
}
```

The problem I am facing is that, I am not using a form, but an anchor tag link. So I am not sure how to add ajax to this.

Answer (score 0):

Your current code is not the best way to do what you want to achieve. But you are almost close.

`$link.attr('action')` will try to fetch the action attribute of the anchor tag. But in your html

`<li><a href="{% url 'visualize' %}" class='link1'>Line Chart</a></li>`

there is no such attribute. I think you got confused by the action and method attribute of `<form>` element

Two solutions.

1. Either use the action and method in the form tag as proper usage and use that in your code.

   ```
   <form id="myForm" method="GET" action="https://google.com">
   ```

and use Jquery

```
$('#myForm').attr('method')
$('#myForm').attr('action')
```

2. Or add the attributes method and action as custom attributes to your anchor tag.

   ```
   <a href="{% url 'visualize' %}" class='link1' method="GET" action="https://google.com">Line Chart</a>
   ```

Now your code should work

**Adding an edit to this answer to fit OP's question format.**

```
<a id="link" href="https://google.com/q?" data-query="cat" data-method="GET">Search for cat</a>

$('#link').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('href'),
    type: $(this).attr('method'),
    data: $(this).attr('cat'),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
      console.log(data)
    },
  })
})
```

Comment: You shouldn't add nonstandard attributes to tags. Use `data-action`.

Comment: What should I add in the data-action? cause the href tag contains the code to what should happen when the link is pressed right?

Comment: Since you are insisting in using submitting form using anchor, use the href as the serve endpoint to submit and leave the action attribute altogether.

Comment: Edited the answer

Comment: I just have one more doubt. While I understand your example, I am not quite sure what to add in the data of the ajax function for my use case.

Comment: data property will send some data to the server. If you don't want to pass any data to the server, then ignore that variable.